# How can I set the length of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

the thing is I don't know if I can set the length of an array in Ruby, I want to set the length of an array with the length of 10 without writing 10 variables inside, is this possible, if so how can I do it?

Comment: Always check out the language API: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/  It'll save you hours of trial and error.

Comment: What exactly to you mean by "set the length of 10 without writing 10 variables inside"? And what counts as a `variable`? The 'length' of an array is defined as the number of elements in the array. Would you count a `nil` as a `variable`? A `string`? Everything is *something*. Do you want an array with 10 nothings?

Comment: Aside from `Array.new(10) #=>  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`, you could write `[nil]*10` or `arr = []; arr[9] = nil`, both of which return an array of 10 `nil` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

If you just want an array of `nil`s of length `size` then:

```
a = Array.new(size)
```

If you want an array of something other than `nil`, then:

```
a = Array.new(size, default_value)
a = [default_value] * size
```

will work but beware that these can lead to problems if `default_value` is mutable. Both of these share one reference for all elements so strange things can happen if you're not aware of the reference sharing; for example:

```
a = Array.new(6, 'pointer')
# ["pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "pointer"] 
a[0].upcase!
# "POINTER" 
a
# ["POINTER", "POINTER", "POINTER", "POINTER", "POINTER", "POINTER"]
```

Many things in Ruby are mutable so `Array.new(size, default_value)` is rarely what you want. If you're using booleans, `nil`s, numbers, frozen strings, symbols, and the like then this is fine because you can't change those and the reference sharing won't bite you.

You can also supply a block to `Array.new`:

```
a = Array.new(6) { 'unique' }
```

That block will be executed for each entry so you want get any surprise reference sharing:

```
a = Array.new(6) { 'unique' }
# ["unique", "unique", "unique", "unique", "unique", "unique"] 
a[0].upcase!
# "UNIQUE" 
a
# ["UNIQUE", "unique", "unique", "unique", "unique", "unique"]
```

This is usually the one you want. Sure, it can consume more memory and take more time to create the array but if either of those is significant then you're probably taking the wrong approach in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array of the given size with the elements set to `nil`:

```
Array.new(size)
```

Elements set to the given value:

```
Array.new(size, "string")
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html

Comment: But strings are mutable so `Array.new(size) { "string" }` would be subject to fewer surprises.

Comment: But at least it would be correct and free from surprising side effects. And we're only talking about ten elements here.

Comment: Using that form of the array constructor is broken and leads to surprising behavior when the default value is mutable. Consider `a = Array.new(size, "string"); a[0].upcase!`.

Comment: That would not be efficient for large data sets. The constructor works as designed.